# Keeping CAShapeLayer Mask Static During Animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to rotate a UIImageView within a circular mask (which is set with myImageView.layer.mask). The problem is that any time I attempt to rotate said UIImageView, the mask rotates with it. Here is some code.

Setting up the mask:

```
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, - 169)
                                                        radius:191 
                                                    startAngle:0.0
                                                      endAngle:2*M_PI 
                                                     clockwise:YES];    

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer  = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shapeLayer setFrame:myImageView.bounds];
    [shapeLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
    myImageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

Animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kRotationTime animations:^(void){        
    myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}];
```

And that's basically all there is to it. A UIImageView rotating about its own center within a fixed-position circular mask--that's the desired effect. Perhaps there is another way to structure the view hierarchy so that myImageView and the mask are siblings, but I haven't had luck going that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the image view into an additional plain UIView superview. Set the layer mask on the superview. Animate the image view.